# Why does the text of UILabel not truncate given the constraints that I have set?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

Quite a simple setup: a `UITableViewCell` hosting a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

The `UIImageView` has got a leading anchor to the cell and a fixed width.
The `UILabel` has got a leading anchor to the UIImageView, a trailing anchor to the cell and is centred vertically. `numberOfLines` is set to `1`, `lineBreakMode` is set to `.byTruncatingTail` and `Autoshrink` to `Fixed font size`.

From my understanding this are all conditions necessary in order to make the label truncate the text. However, it does not. Why?

Constraints: 
[image: Constraints]

Properties: 
[image: Properties]

Result: 
[image: Result]

Comment: Is the last picture your current output or the desired one? How is it not truncating the string? I mean what happens to the string at the moment?

Comment: The last picture is the current output. It is not desired because the text of the label extends until the end of the screen and then gets cut off. I want the text of the label to end roughly 15 points before the end of the screen, hence my trailingAnchor.

Comment: Ok I programmatically created a class for you

Comment: I feel like we're missing information, because this should just work. What does your table view's trailing constraint look like? Maybe the table view itself is extending beyond the right edge for some reason.

Comment: @Tyler Agreed, the core problem seems to be somewhere further up the hierarchy. The tableView is pinned to the edges of its parentView, which is a navigationController. This navigationController takes up 50% of the contentSize in a horizontal scrollView - alongside another navigationController. This scrollView is pinned to the edges of the rootView (top of the hierarchy).

Comment: After rebuilding my view hierarchy in a new project it looks like the problem arises from having two navigationControllers inside of a scrollView. The tableView inside of the left navigationController extends beyond the frame of the left navigationController into the frame of the right navigationController.

Answer (score 3):

Use this class. Edit the values as you please.
I highly recommend you programmatically create cells. Constraints are a tricky business and you'll have a hard time setting them. Here I'm defining the size of the objects and their place inside of the cell. This is way is easier and cleaner in my opinion.

```swift
class tabViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var label: UILabel!
    var myImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
      commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
   
    func commonInit() {
        //Space between items
        let sideSpace: CGFloat = 15.0
        //Hight of image and label and width of image
        let imageDimension: CGFloat = 25.0
        //width of image + space between beginning of your cell and image + space between image and label
        let labelX: CGFloat = imageDimension+(sideSpace*2)
        //Dimension of the screen - space occupied by first side space, image and space between image and label - space between label and the end of your cell
        //If you want to determine the dimension of the cell use contentView instead of UIScreen.main
        let labelWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width-labelX-sideSpace
        
        
        myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: sideSpace, y: 0.0, width: imageDimension, height: imageDimension))
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: labelX, y: 0.0, width: labelWidth, height: imageDimension))
        
        label.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15) //Change it as you please
        
        addSubview(myImageView)
        addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mary. That works indeed but it uses frames instead of autoLayout constraints. I know how to do it with frames but wanted to do it with autoLayout constraints instead. Still, thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh I see... I'm sorry I couldn't help more

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should work and it is working for me. Please find the screens below. I recommend doing the same setup in a different controller and try to figure out the root cause.

Just remember, the label will truncate in storyboard itself so no need to run it to test, just give a long string in storyboard.

**Constraints:**

[image: Constraints]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for the hint with trying it out in the .xib file. It does truncate if I add a long string in the .xib file but then once I run the app the UILabel seems to ignore the constraints and extend until the end of the screen.

Comment: Maybe your capture your view during run time and debug

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
let labelWidth = CGRectGetWidth(label.bounds)

    let str = "You will have 30 seconds till you give us a good impression" as NSString
    let words = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var newStr = "" as NSString

    for word in words{

        let statement = "\(newStr) \(word) ..." as NSString
        let size = statement.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:label.font])
        if size.width < labelWidth {
            newStr = "\(newStr) \(word)"
        }
        else{
           break
        }
    }

    newStr = newStr.stringByAppendingString(" ...")

    self.label.text = newStr as String
```

Use this in your storyboard constrains:

1- give the label (Trailing, leading, top & Bottom)

2- Number of lines = 1

3- you can center your label with imageView

[image]

It already works with me:

[image]

Comment: Haha, yep that should work but this solution feels a bit like shooting with cannons on birds. I mean the UILabel class should do this automatically if it recognises that the length of the text exceeds its size. The real problem here seems to be that the constraints somehow don't work. Still, thank you!

Comment: you can set a fixed width for the label (greater than or equal)

Comment: check my updated comment, it works normally

Comment: Thank you for updating your comment. I see that it works for you but it doesn't work for me although I have set the exact same constraints and properties. It is still the same like in the screenshots I posted in my question.

Comment: if available upload your project and put the link to check it

Comment: I can't because it's closed source but I will try to replicate it now in a new project. Will take a few minutes.